Contour integrals of operators in radial quantization of 2d CFT
In Di francesco's Conformal Field Theory book he arrives at the equation (6.15)
$$\oint_C dz\; a(z)b(w)=[A,b(w)]\tag{6.15}$$
where $a(z)$ and $b(w)$ are $\textbf{holomorphic}$ fields, the contour $C$ circles counterclockwise around $w$, in the left hand side there is an implicit radial ordering and
\begin{equation}
A=\oint dz\;a(z).\tag{6.16}
\label{gay}
\end{equation}
My question is, since $a(z)$ is holomorphic, how is $A$ not zero in virtue of Cauchy's theorem?
I think I'm missing something related to the operator character of this objects, for I understand that the presence of $b(w)$ in (6.15) might cause a singularity at $z=w$ (as we usually see in OPEs) thus making the integrals not vanishing but I can't reconciliate this with the expresion for $A$ alone.
For example this comes up when writing the Virasoro generators in terms of the energy-momentum tensor as
$$L_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint dz\; z^{n+1} T(z)$$
since I'm told $T(z)$ is holomorphic and following this reasoning this would make $L_n=0$ for $n\geq -1$, which is false.


Briefly speaking, as OP already suggests, the operator $a(z)$ is only holomorphic/complex differentiable away from other operator insertions and branch points, which in turn, affect the topological codimension-1 operator $$A(C)~:=~\oint_{C} dz~a(z)\tag{6.16},$$ where $C$ is an integration contour.

Note in particular that in the operator product $a(z)b(w)$ [which is typically singular for $z\!-\!w\to 0$], the $(z,w)$-dependence does not factorize.

For more details, see e.g. this related Phys.SE post.



So the integral forms of $A$ and $L_n$ should be understood as: first apply the integrand and then integrate? If so, why can't we integrate before aplying? I think what is confusing is that $a(z)b(w)$ is not holomorphic when $a(z)$ and $b(w)$ separately are, which would obviously not be true if they were just functions.

$a(z)b(w)$ not being holomorphic was confusing to me, too. But I guess one can't expect them to behave like functions $-$ their composition as operators is more non-trivial than the multiplication of two functions.
